# How does searching a file (locate) or autocompletion work?

Tags: search

I am a Windows user and coming from Windows with all the indexing and eternal wait times when searching for files, I find it surprising how fast does *locate* work or the autocompletion (that I know) work in linux.

Is there any indexing being done in the background or how is this achieved? I still have a pretty clean installation, so maybe this goes bad with time, but in Windows the moment you want to search on a folder which is not indexed you have to wait for some seconds.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I find it surprising how fast does locate work or the autocompletion (that I know) work in linux. ... Is there any indexing being done in the background or how is this achieved?

This is actually two completely distinct questions.

`locate` uses an index (slocate stores it in `/var/lib/slocate/`), that is updated by a nightly `cron` job. This nightly job *typically* runs at about 1 or 2AM local time, and completely scans your entire system (including all connected drives). The resulting index is simply a list of filenames.

Auto-complete is handled by your shell. Most systems use `bash`, so `bash-completion` is the collection of scripts that manage how this works. (`zsh` has a similarly-named collection, and most of the other shells have some form of completion built-in.) When <kbd>Tab</kbd> is pressed, the shell runs a script that decides, based on what you've typed already, what, exactly, needs to be completed. The script then generates a list of possible completions, which may or may not be the list of files in the current directory, or the list of executable files in your `$PATH`. The `locate` command is normally *not* used for this.

Comment: Thanks! I see, so it's not so "magical" :)

Comment: greyfade has ruined the magic forever -_-

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: Sorry. :(

Comment: The shell runs a script sounds not 100% correct, when implementing a shell people shouldn't be misguided in thinking they should write external scripts. It's simply a routine in the code itself, it may or not access external files for configuration convenience, but simple built-in completion works well.

Comment: @Aki: The majority of customized autocompletion in bash is implemented by scripts in `/etc/bash_completion.d/`. You're right, they need not be shell scripts, but most of the time they are. (zsh keeps its completion scripts in `/usr/share/zsh/site-functions/`)

Comment: @greyfade bash_completion is not part of bash. It is an external project handled by Debian. It has nothing to do with what happens by default when you press Tab in a bash shell :-)

Comment: @ChrisDown: I'm aware of this. But `bash-completion` is offered in most distros, sometimes installed by default. I named the package specifically for those who don't have it and want to install it.

Comment: So deleting of file is still being shown using locate. :-) Thank you

Comment: I cannot find /var/lib/slocate on ubuntu 14.04 though

Comment: @NabinKhadka Since my answer was written, I think Ubuntu changed to another `locate` service. I don't know which one - I don't use Ubuntu - but mlocate comes to mind. Check `/etc/updatedb.conf`. It may have the default path for whichever `locate` tool you have.

Answer (score 5):

Usually, locate uses an index which is generated once a day via a cron-job (/etc/cron.daily/mlocate on my system for example). It does nothing fancy, basically a complete filesystem traversal with some optimizations and the building of the index data structure.

Shells use probably some internal caching for command completion, but does not use a global index file. Besides, usually, Unix kernels maintain a dentry-cache, i.e.\ they cache file directory information used by directory listings etc. in memory (including the stat'ing of non-existent files - which is also called inverse caching).